# Adding a fixed header/footer for each page jsPDF

Tags: html, header, addition, footer, jspdf

I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate PDF's out of dynamic HTML content of my web-application.
Right now I am trying to give those PDF's a unique layout. I want to add a "header" & "footer" for each page of my PDF. jsPDF generates page breaks automaticly and there is no command to act on those.

Is there any known work-a-round to implement a fixed header/footer for each page without depending on doc.addPage();

Looking forward for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/260

You can use HTML's elements `<header>` and `<footer>` for that purpose, for example:

```
<footer>
    <div style='text-align:center;'>Page <span class="pageCounter"></span>/<span class="totalPages"></span></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thanks @diegocr that helps a lot. Now all I gotta figure out is how to set background-color's.

Comment: Unfortunately the fromHTML plugin is quite limited when it comes to supporting css styles, being background colors ignored atm.

Comment: Is it possible to add footer without using addHTML?

Comment: What if you need to add a header and footer that's not visible on the html page?