# Html table to PDF I want to format it (Page numbers, second page is bad)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, jspdf

I have a format problem, the header of my html table is on each side (with whom I could live) but it look so terrible (Picture bellow).
And then i wan't to insert page numbers in the PDF file (i don't know how to do that).

My Javascript

```
function makePDF() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter');
            source = $('#PDF')[0];

            specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
                    return true
                }
            };
            margins = {
                top: 80,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 40,
                width: 522
            };
            pdf.fromHTML(
                    source,
                    margins.left, 
                    margins.top, {
                        'width': margins.width, 
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    },
            function(dispose) {
                    $Titel=document.getElementById('TitelPDF').value;

                    if(! $Titel==""){
                        document.getElementById("TitelPDF").style.borderColor="";
                        $TitelPDF=$Titel+'.pdf';
                        pdf.save($TitelPDF);
                    } else {
                        alert("Insert a Title");
                        document.getElementById("TitelPDF").style.borderColor="red";
                    }
            }
            , margins);
        }
```

My html table (with values from Mysql)

```
    <?php  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM person");
                $statement->execute(array());

                echo '<style type="text/css"> table, td, th { width: 55em; border-collapse: collapse; 
                        background: white; color: black; border: 1px solid #333; } </style>';
                echo '<table id="table">';
                    echo'<thead>';
                        echo'<tr id="tr">';
                            echo "<th>". "Vorname". "</th>";
                            echo "<th>". "Nachname". "</th>";
                            echo "<th>". "Ortschaft". "</th>";
                            echo "<th>". "Tel_Mobil". "</th>";
                            echo "<th>". "Mail". "</th>";
                            echo "<th>". "AHV". "</th>";
                        echo "</tr>";                   
                    echo'</thead>';
                    echo'<tbody>';
                    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                        echo '<tr id="tr">';
                            echo "<td>". $row['Vorname']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row['Nachname']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row['Ortschaft']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row['Tel_Mobil']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row['Mail']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row['AHV']."</td>";
                    }
                        echo'</tr>';
                    echo'</tbody>';
                echo '</table><br>';

                echo '<form action="../html/Navigation.html" method="post"> <input type="Submit" name="zurück" value="zurück"> </form>';
            }
        ?>
```

a Picture of my PDF:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Comment: This may help with page numbering : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989285/adding-a-fixed-header-footer-for-each-page-jspdf

Comment: Thank you but i can't built this in my script :( I have nowhere a addPage().

Comment: Did you look at the answer (with further link) which uses a footer element & does not use addPage.

Comment: Can you give my an example I'm an js beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2nd line of the makePDF function from

```
source = $('#PDF')[0];
```

to the following two lines

```
source = $("content").innerHTML;
source += "<footer><div style='text-align:center;'>Page <span class=\"pageCounter\"></span>/<span class=\"totalPages\"></span></div></footer>";
```

Or you could leave the function unchanged & echo the footer section after the table you generate, but that would display incorrectly on the web page, although adding page numbering to the PDF.

Comment: Thank you I have tried it. But i doesn't work... The PDF represent all very terrible i have 389 Pages and 388 are empty. My table is in addition nowhere. It doesn't depends on "source = $("what i write here").innerHTML;". And that with the echo i tried too but with the same effect. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I did test that myself, though I used a statically generated web page & table rather than using php to dynamically create things. Did you try echoing the footer section after you have generated the table.